# How to show Array of Dictionaries in a SwiftUI List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

After a few months of learning Swift by migrating parts of a legacy ObjC app, I'm looking forward to starting a new app in pure Swift - I'm hoping that working with pure Swift base classes will lead to less unwrapping and other bridging shenanigans.

However, very quickly I've found myself facing similar problems.

I want to read some JSON from a web service, and show in in a list implemented with SwiftUI - should be simple, right?

The data (actually read from the Twitter API) comes in, and I deserialise it,

```
    do {
        if let results = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments  ) as? [String: Any] {
            print(results)
            if let followers = results["users"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                print (followers.count)
                print("followers class \(type(of: followers))")
            } else {
                print(results["errors"])
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

You'll see I print the class of followers, and this shows,

```
followers class Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
```

...a nice array of Dictionaries, using Swift base classes.  That would seem a reasonable data structure to present via a List in SwiftUI.  However, it doesn't seem to be so simple, as the data elements need to be Identifiable (fair enough) but I don't have a struct for each element, and I don't want the overhead of processing the array into an array of structs carrying identifiers.

A bit of research, and it seems there's a solution available, as I can initialise List with an Array, something like the following,

```
var body: some View {
    List (twitter.followers!, id: \.self) { follower in // <<< Compilation error
        Text("\(follower["name"])")
    }
}
```

However, that code gives the compilation error on the flagged line,

> Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Hashable' because only concrete
>   types can conform to protocols

I think the issue is that the compiler sees followers as 'Any', rather than an Array, but why?

btw, I've seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329861/array-of-dictionaries-to-list-view-swiftui), but it seems the List initialiser should be a more elegant solution, if I can get it to work...

Comment: The problem is the `Any` as the type for the values in the dictionary and not the array itself. Best way forward is probably to use structs after all or map your dictionary values to a specific type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a struct for follower/user and declare it as `Decodable` and `Identifiable`.

Then you will be able to use `JSONDecoder` to read the data from the struct into an array for you.

As a result your twitter.followers will be an array of identifiable objects and you will be able to use it in `ForEach()`.